# SQL Script using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query below using CTE. I am wondering if there are some approach other than this. So I am collecting some advise to refactor it. Any advise please. Or does the query look good even I am using this `IN (SELECT InvariantLanguageCultureCode FROM y)` statement many times in the query?

```
DECLARE  @ReportingInstanceID INT

SET @ReportingInstanceID=34
;WITH x AS (
    SELECT  [dbo].[tenant_Reporting_Instance].UserID
    FROM    [dbo].[tenant_Reporting_Instance]
    WHERE   tenant_Reporting_Instance.ReportingInstanceID = @ReportingInstanceID
), y AS ( 
    SELECT  [TRCCore].[dbo].[pr_Language].InvariantLanguageCultureCode
    FROM    [TRCCore].[dbo].[pr_Language]
    JOIN [dbo].[tenant_User_Setting] 
        ON tenant_User_Setting.LanguageID = pr_Language.LanguageID
    WHERE   tenant_User_Setting.UserID IN (
                SELECT UserID FROM x
    )
), Default_User_Settings_CTE ( RoundingTypeInvariantCode, AgingDateValue
                             , CurrencyLabel, JobZoneLinkTypeLabel, MatchPeriodLabel
                             , PayFrequencyLabel, PayTypeLabel )
    AS ( SELECT   r.RoundingTypeInvariantCode ,
                  a.AgingDateValue ,
                  cur.CurrencyLabel ,
                  jz.JobZoneLinkTypeLabel ,
                  m.MatchPeriodLabel ,
                  pf.PayFrequencyLabel ,
                  pt.PayTypeLabel
         FROM     dbo.tenant_User_Setting s
         JOIN TRCCore.dbo.pr_Rounding_Type r 
             ON r.RoundingTypeID = s.RoundingTypeID
         JOIN dbo.tenant_Aging_Date a 
             ON a.AgingDateID = s.AgingDateID
         JOIN TRCCore.dbo.translation_pr_Currency cur 
             ON cur.CurrencyID = s.CurrencyID
             AND cur.LanguageCultureCode IN ( SELECT InvariantLanguageCultureCode 
                                              FROM y)
         JOIN dbo.translation_tenant_Job_Zone_Link_Type jz 
             ON jz.JobZoneLinkTypeID = s.JobZoneLinkTypeID
             AND jz.LanguageCultureCode IN (  SELECT InvariantLanguageCultureCode 
                                              FROM y)
         JOIN dbo.tenant_Match_Period m 
             ON m.MatchPeriodID = s.MatchPeriodID
         JOIN dbo.translation_tenant_Pay_Frequency pf 
             ON pf.PayFrequencyID = s.PayFrequencyID
             AND pf.LanguageCultureCode IN (SELECT InvariantLanguageCultureCode 
                                            FROM y)
         JOIN dbo.translation_app_Pay_Type pt 
             ON pt.PayTypeID = s.PayTypeID
             AND pt.LanguageCultureCode IN (SELECT InvariantLanguageCultureCode 
                                            FROM y)
         WHERE    s.UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM x)
    )
    SELECT * FROM Default_User_Settings_CTE
```

Comment: Is this working as expected? If yes, please move your question to codereview.stackexchange.com to get advice on improving it. If not, please state what error you get with this query.

Comment: Oh I see. thanks. I didn't encounter any errors. My question is if there are some other ways other than my implementation. Anyway, I have posted my question to the site you've referred.

Comment: In some DBs, you may get better performance by replacing the `IN` on InvariantLanguageCultureCode with a `JOIN`. You can use parentheses to make a separate join with `y` for each table, since AFAICT you don't require the LanguageCultureCode to be the same in `pt`, `pf`, `jz`, just that it be in the `y` list.

Comment: OK thanks. Andrew Lazarus. I just realized it in a few minutes. I have updated the query

Answer (score 0):

Populate the result of the query into a temp table so that it can be reused as many times as needed.